# Does windows api messages still exists?

Tags: c#, windows, api

Long long time ago (in a galaxy far away), I used to program some fun tools to assist me (as having a disability) or just support my lazyness :)
Tools that do things like "wait 30 seconds and then press play on my media player" or "save a list of all song names from winamp that streaming a live m3u based radio". it was almost 20 years ago, using C# and window messages api (not wanting to relay on mouse clicks and strict window size&position). I would've found the window's handle and the "control" handle and interact with it.

The question is: Can I still do it today in the age of Windows 10?
If so, how?
I would appreciate a starting point.

Let's say I want to press play on my bs.player after x seconds, or close an error message that comes up every 10 seconds (well, its not cause' my windows is healthy ..but theoretically).

Thank you :)

Comment: Windows desktop applications still use the same Win32 APIs found primarily in USER32.DLL including window handles and messages.  "Modern UI" (sometimes called Metro, Store apps, etc) do not use USER32.DLL and do not interact the same way.

Comment: Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is the last name for *Modern UI* and Metro, this last had caused a word conflict problem. It requires 10 GB more in the VS install !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, if you talk about Windows API.

You need to declare the external WinAPI's signatures as `static extern` using the [DllImport attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute).

For example to know if the screen saver is active or if an app runs in full screen:

```
private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
private const int SC_SCREENSAVE = 0xF140;
private const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 0x0072;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int action, int param, ref int retval, int updini);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct RECT
{
  public int left;
  public int top;
  public int right;
  public int bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static private extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, [In, Out] ref RECT rect);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static private extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

static private bool IsForegroundFullScreen()
{
  return IsForegroundFullScreen(null);
}

static private bool IsForegroundFullScreen(Screen screen)
{
  if ( screen == null ) screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
  RECT rect = new RECT();
  GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(null, GetForegroundWindow()), ref rect);
  return new Rectangle(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top)
             .Contains(screen.Bounds);
}

private bool IsScreensaverActive()
{
  int active = 1;
  SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, ref active, 0);
  return active != 0;
}

private bool IsForegroundFullScreenOrScreensaver()
{
  return IsForegroundFullScreen() || IsScreensaverActive();
}
```

[Calling Win32 DLLs in C#](https://lonewolfonline.net/calling-win32-dlls/)

[c# dllimport with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992178/c-sharp-dllimport-with-pointers)