# How to declare extern methods with pointers and callbacks in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, dllimport

I have a .dll compiled from C code that exposes the following function:

```
int decompress(long length, uint8_t* input, int callback(void*, const uint8_t*, long), void* callback_data)
```

The returned int is (potentially) an error code, and the actual result of the call is returned to the callback. `length` is the length of a byte array of data, and I'm fairly certain the `uint8_t*` is a pointer to said byte array. From the method itself, it looks to me like `callback_data` is a pointer to a byte array that the function `decompress` can write to, but I'm not sure what a void pointer is or how it's used. Lastly, the `callback` function's three parameters are apparently the pointer to the callback data, the output and the size of the output (again, I'm guessing byte array).

I'm trying call this function from C#. I've used `DLLImport` several times before, but I'm not sure how to deal with this kind of function signature. Do I need `unsafe` code in C# and pass pointers the `extern` method I define in C#, or can I stick to managed code? If so, how? What would that C# code look like? In particular, what would the method signature be when I want to pass a callback function into the exposed function from the dll?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# dllimport with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992178/c-sharp-dllimport-with-pointers)

Comment: Not quite, unfortunately. It does not really make it clear what is required when the function signature takes in pointers, and what that requires from the corresponding method signature in C#.